# How to redirect to /dashboard public routes /login and /register if user is logged in and in all other cases show public routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two types of routes Public and Private.

All private routes are accessible only if user is logged in:

```
return tokenService.token 
  ? (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner className="spinner" />}>
        <Outlet />
      </Suspense>
      <Footer />
    </>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={'/login'} replace />
  );
```

Then we have public routes. Which can be accessible anywhere but `/login` and `/registration` routes even they are public if user is logged in they should be redirected to /`dashboard` in all other cases we show public route.

This is our file for public route

```
return (
  <>
    <AuthHeader />
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner className="spinner" />}>
      <Outlet />
    </Suspense>
    <Footer />
  </>
)
```

Main routes file

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
    <Route path={'/login'} element={<Login />} />
    <Route
      path={'/registration'}
      element={<Registration />}
    />
    <Route path={'/terms'} element={<Terms />} />
    <Route path={'/privacy'} element={<Privacy />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<AuthRoute />}>
    <Route path={'/dashboard'} element={<MyProfile />} /> 
  </Route>
  <Route path={'/notfound'} element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

So what would be the most efficient way to redirect `"/login"` and `"/registration"` routes to `"/dashboard"` route if user is logged in and in all other cases show public routes?

So user should be able to access `"/terms"` from anywhere but if he is logged in then he doesn't have access to `"/login"` and `"/registration"` routes (redirect to `"/dashboard"`).

In current code even user is logged in he can access to all public routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an anonymous route protector for the log-in and dashboard routes that does the inverse of the private route protector.

Example:

```
const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  return tokenService.token
    ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
    <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route
        path="/registration"
        element={<Registration />}
      />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
    <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<AuthRoute />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<MyProfile />} /> 
  </Route>
  <Route path="/notfound" element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user is logged in or not in each of login and registration page. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      userInfo?.user?.role === 'admin'
        ? navigate('/dashboard')
        : userInfo?.user?.role === 'client'
        ? navigate('/client-dashboard')
        : navigate('/translator-dashboard');
      return;
    }
  }, [])
```

In above snippet. what I did is to check if logged in user role. Based on user role I have navigate user to respective page. For your case you can do similar like this you have to check in login and registration page. Hope this concept will help you.